# How to execute alt+enter same way resharper on VS

Tags: resharper, rider

When using `Visual Studio` with `Resharper` when i make new `interface's method` on fly i just `right-click` on it and doing `alt+Enter` then there is option to add it to existing `interface`. Nevertheless when i use `Jet Brains Rider` doing same i do not see an option. I tried also doing `alt+insert` but list doesn't have what i need. What is equivalent shortcut option in rider to have same option? See example below when i click `alt+insert` in `Rider` i do not see add to `interface` option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same way in Rider as in ReSharper. Wait for Rider to color the new method call red, then Alt+Enter -> "Create method ...".

[image]